# Ionic 3 - inline video opens in fullscreen in native player on iOS 10

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to play a video inline within an ionic 3 mobile app - I'd like to avoid launching the native video player.

I'm testing on iPhone 5s - iOS 10.

Here's a function I created for loading videos according to everything I've read:

```
loadVideo(src: string, onComplete?: (src: string) => void): void {
    var video: HTMLVideoElement = document.createElement('video');

    video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
    video.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', '');
    video.setAttribute('src', src);

    var onVideoLoaded = () => {
        video.removeEventListener('loadeddata', onVideoLoaded);

        if (onComplete != null) onComplete(src);
    };

    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', onVideoLoaded);

    video.load();
}
```

After the load is complete, I'm playing it via video.play().

Another version of this function is:

```
loadVideo(src: string, onComplete?: (src: string) => void): void {
    var video: HTMLVideoElement = document.createElement('video');

    video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
    video.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', '');

    var srcElement: HTMLSourceElement = document.createElement('source');

    srcElement.setAttribute('src', src);
    srcElement.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4');

    var onVideoLoaded = () => {
        video.removeEventListener('loadeddata', onVideoLoaded);

        if (onComplete != null) onComplete(src);
    };

    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', onVideoLoaded);

    video.appendChild(srcElement);
    video.load();
}
```

which uses the source element instead of the source attribute in the video element.

I also tried writing a video tag directly in HTML in case Angular has some code under the hood that takes care of this:

```
<video playsinline webkit-playsinline autoplay muted">
    <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Since autoplay isn't supposed to supported for videos that are not muted I tried to add the muted attribute as well via HTML.
When adding it via JavaScript it doesn't seem to have an effect when adding it as an attribute, instead I'm writing video.muted = true.

Another thing I tried was to play a muted video it with user interaction instead of autoplaying it:

```
window.addEventListener('pointerdown', () => video.play());
```

I also tried to use this polyfill which is supposed to imitate iOS 10's playsinline on iOS 8 and 9:

```
enableInlineVideo(video, false);
```

https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video

Everything I tried ends up having the same result - on iOS the video is played in fullscreen in the native player even though it's supposed to play inline, and on Android it plays inline as expected.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Did you tried with the following in your `config.xml`

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
```

Which Triggers the Native app to play in Inline. while coming to the HTML5 there is a intresting fact that was stated in [Apple Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

> on iPhone and iPod touch, which are small screen devices, "Video is
>   NOT presented within the Web Page"

Comment: I read so many articles and issues regarding inline videos and none mentioned that little piece of information. That solved my issue, thanks :)

Comment: It's still playing it in fullscreen on my iPhone.

Comment: You need to do a rebuild by cleaning again

Comment: Where does this go? Because when I place it in config under iOS it gets overwritten?

Comment: @OliverDixon you need to add it inside the `config.xml` of your `ionic` folder structure

Comment: @Webruster what does this mean, what directory? We have one inside ios/App/App but it gets overwritten each time.

Comment: @OliverDixon i mean inside the ionic-starter template, you will have `config.xml` which is on root , this is the place where we add this configuration

Comment: @Webruster there's no config.xml, and adding one does nothing. I figured it out; I was using a capacitor that doesn't need one. The documentation for Ionic is appalling.

Answer (score 1):

It actually takes two things and it DOES work on the iPhone:

Add this to config.xml

`<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />`

And in the HTML you must include webkit-playsinline

`<video webkit-playsinline playsinline autoplay muted loop><source src='vid/vid.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>`

Duplicate for

[Phonegap iOS HTML5 Video Opens Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491074/phonegap-ios-html5-video-opens-player)

credits to @a432511

Comment: Which directory is your config? Our one keeps getting overwritten on iOS.

Comment: When editing the config file, make sure no `ng serve`-process is running, or the config file will be overwritten on quit.